# Changing background-position-x on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am using Ian Lunn's Parallax tutorial http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/. I'd like to build on this to not only change the y-position of the background, but also the x-position on scroll. This would basically add horizontal movement as well as vertical so that some of the objects move in both directions.

For an example of what I'd like to do http://www.nikebetterworld.com/product. The 3rd scene, where the car comes in is the movement I am trying to achieve.

His original code is:

```
//function that is called for every pixel the user scrolls. Determines the position of the background
/*arguments: 
    x = horizontal position of background
    y = vertical position of the background
    windowHeight = height of the viewport
    pos = position of the scrollbar
    adjuster = adjust the position of the background
    inertia = how fast the background moves in relation to scrolling
    backgroundPosition-y = original background position vertical
*/
function newPos(x, windowHeight, pos, adjuster, inertia){
    return x + "% " + (-((windowHeight + pos) - adjuster) * inertia)  + "px";
}

//function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
function Move(){ 
    var pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar

    //if the first section is in view...
    if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
        //call the newPos function and change the background position
        $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(20, windowHeight, pos, 300, 0.1)}); 
        sun_1.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(10, windowHeight, pos, 4000, .1)});
        deer.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(40, windowHeight, pos, 500, .1)});
    }
```

I'm sure this is very, very wrong to do, but here's what I've tried.

```
sun_1.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(10, windowHeight, pos, 4000, .1)}, {'background-position-x': '0% ' + parseInt(-xx/ 10) + 'px'});
```

Is there a way to either add this to the "newPos" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out something that works.

```
sun_1.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos((3+pos/50), windowHeight, pos, 4000, .2)});
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it seems to work okay. The first number defines the starting position (in this case, 3%), the second number grabs the position of the window in relation to the scroll, and the third number determines the speed of movement.

To change the direction of movement along x, change "50" to a negative number.